# WP-API custom post type with custom taxonomy

Tags: json, rest, wordpress

I'm fighting with https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API I'm trying to add in a custom post type with a custom taxonomy called listing_categy: 
Querying this endpoint:

http://example.com/subfolder/wp-json/taxonomies/listing_categy/terms

gives me this:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 9,
    "name": "buying",
    "slug": "buying-2",
    "description": "",
    "parent": null,
    "count": 1,
    "link": "http:\/\/example.com\/subfolder\/listing_categy\/buying-2\/",
    "meta": {
      "links": {
        "collection": "http:\/\/example.com\/subfolder\/wp-json\/taxonomies\/listing_categy\/terms",
        "self": "http:\/\/example.com\/subfolder\/wp-json\/taxonomies\/listing_categy\/terms\/7"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "ID": 10,
    "name": "selling",
    "slug": "selling-2",
    "description": "",
    "parent": null,
    "count": 0,
    "link": "http:\/\/example.com\/subfolder\/listing_categy\/selling-2\/",
    "meta": {
      "links": {
        "collection": "http:\/\/example.com\/subfolder\/wp-json\/taxonomies\/listing_categy\/terms",
        "self": "http:\/\/example.com\/subfolder\/wp-json\/taxonomies\/listing_categy\/terms\/8"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the php file that handles the posting is this https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/master/lib/class-wp-json-posts.php :

```
  /**
   * Create a new post for any registered post type.
   *
   * @since 3.4.0
   * @internal 'data' is used here rather than 'content', as get_default_post_to_edit uses $_REQUEST['content']
   *
   * @param array $content Content data. Can contain:
   *  - post_type (default: 'post')
   *  - post_status (default: 'draft')
   *  - post_title
   *  - post_author
   *  - post_excerpt
   *  - post_content
   *  - post_date_gmt | post_date
   *  - post_format
   *  - post_password
   *  - comment_status - can be 'open' | 'closed'
   *  - ping_status - can be 'open' | 'closed'
   *  - sticky
   *  - post_thumbnail - ID of a media item to use as the post thumbnail/featured image
   *  - custom_fields - array, with each element containing 'key' and 'value'
   *  - terms - array, with taxonomy names as keys and arrays of term IDs as values
   *  - terms_names - array, with taxonomy names as keys and arrays of term names as values
   *  - enclosure
   *  - any other fields supported by wp_insert_post()
   * @return array Post data (see {@see WP_JSON_Posts::get_post})
   */
  public function new_post( $data ) {
    unset( $data['ID'] );

    $result = $this->insert_post( $data );
    if ( $result instanceof WP_Error ) {
      return $result;
    }

    $response = json_ensure_response( $this->get_post( $result ) );
    $response->set_status( 201 );
    $response->header( 'Location', json_url( '/posts/' . $result ) );

    return $response;
  }
```

I've tried sending the json to the /posts and it works fine for all bar the terms....

I've tried all of the following: 
this:

```
"title": $scope.listobject.listname, "status": "publish", "slug": "selling","type": "listing", "post_meta": $scope.dataform, "terms": { "listing_categy": [9] }
```

this:

```
"title": $scope.listobject.listname, "status": "publish", "slug": "selling","type": "listing", "post_meta": $scope.dataform, "terms": { "listing_categy": [ {"ID": 9 } ]}
```

this:

```
"title": $scope.listobject.listname, "status": "publish", "slug": "selling","type": "listing", "post_meta": $scope.dataform, "terms": { "listing_categy": [9, 10 ] }
```

This:

```
"terms_names": { "listing_categy": ["selling", "buying"] }
```

the documentation is awful

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I've got the same problem.

Comment: I did I'll dig it up one min!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"listing_categy" is about GET, here you have POSTing post parameters 
[form WP-API api docs](http://wp-api.org/#posts_create-a-post)

A quick but dirt solution could be to add some code to *insert_post* in lib/class-wp-json-posts.php.

Insert at line 921:

```
if( ! empty($data['term']))
    {
        $post_custom_tax['term']=$data['term'];
    }
    if( ! empty($data['tax']))
    {
        $post_custom_tax['tax']=$data['tax'];
    }
```

and just after

```
$post_ID = $update ? wp_update_post( $post, true ) : wp_insert_post( $post, true );
```

insert

```
if(!empty($post_custom_tax['term']) && ! empty( $post_custom_tax['tax']))
    {
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_ID, $post_custom_tax['term'], $post_custom_tax['tax'], true ); //with true for appending categories
    }
```

So now add this properties to your json post object looking like

```
"term": "custom-term-slug",
"tax": "custom-tax-slug"
```

*This need to be refactored using filters

Answer (score 6):

Try with this:
[your-site-root-dev-domain]/wp-json/posts/?type=[type-of-your-post]&filter[cat]=35

Please take a look to:
https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/343

Tell me if this help you.

Comment: Your solution is about finding them, not posting.

Comment: @PanMan Yes, and about that is the question. Please, read again.

Answer (score -1):

I used wp-api resource https://github.com/jeffsebring/angular-wp-api then I built my object like this:

```
wpAPIResource.save({ param1: 'posts' },{ "title": $scope.listobject.listname, "slug": $scope.listobject.typeoflist,"type": "listing", "post_meta": $scope.dataform,  "tax_input": { "listing_categy": { "term_names": [$scope.listobject.typeoflist] } } },
```